# BeanFactory and the ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, tnsping

I have this class:

```
@Service
public class SecurityManagerService implements ISecurityManagerService {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final RightRepository rightRepository;

    public SecurityManagerService(UserRepository userRepository,
                                  RoleRepository roleRepository,
                                  RightRepository rightRepository) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.rightRepository = rightRepository;
    }

..
}
```

I want to create the beans for the test classes:

```
   <bean id="userRepository" class="eu.lopo.repositories.security.UserRepository" abstract="true"/>
    
    <bean id="securityManagerService" class="eu.lopo.services.security.SecurityManagerService"  >
        <constructor-arg><ref bean="userRepository"/></constructor-arg>
       
    </bean>
```

but I have the error: `Abstract bean cannot be used here`

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please post more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Create the bean  securityManagerService with the 3 parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better you can use Annotation to inject your dependencies.
Springboot now provides a very elegant and simple way to inject the dependent service.

@Service
public class SecurityManagerService implements ISecurityManagerService {

```
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
private final RightRepository rightRepository;

public SecurityManagerService(@Autowired UserRepository userRepository,
                              @Autowired RoleRepository roleRepository,
                              @Autowired RightRepository rightRepository) {

    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.rightRepository = rightRepository;
}
```

..
}

Or you can use @@Autowired either by setter or purely without using constructor . Hope this gives you some clue.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-di-patterns-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly